# Windows 8.1 plays only 2 speakers of 5.1 system

Tags: windows, audio, windows-8.1, speakers

I used Windows 7 until this afternoon and my 5.1 sound system worked just fine.
My motherboard is a Gigabyte B75M-D3H.

I have 3 inputs on the back panel:

- Line-In
- Line-Out
- Mic

I was able to configure my Windows 7 to accept all these as input (L and R in Line-Out, C and SW to Line-In and RL and RR in Mic).

Today I installed Windows 8.1. It can play only 2 satellite speakers and the rest of them are mute.

I installed the Realtek driver and in the Sound Manager it can play 2 satellites, the subwoofer and the other speakers can't be heard.

In the Windows test program, it can play 2 speakers.

What should I set to make Windows use all of my speakers?

Comment: You did set your speaker config to 5.1, right?

Comment: The Realtek CP that comes with windows is very generic. Get their own from  http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/ …on second thoughts, that pinout indicates you don't have a 5.1 header, only stereo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found it.

If you open the Realtek Audio Manager and select the ***visual representations of the inputs*** by *double click on them*, you can set their behavior.

Here you can see them:

[image]

[image]